# How to handle JSON string in jQuery?

Tags: java, jquery, json

I have a JSON string as following

```
    [{"partner-code":"AMEX",
"partner":"American Express",
"issuer":"American Express",
"summary":[],
"description":[],
"url":"http://www.qantas.com.au/fflyer/dyn/partners/card-american-express",
"email":[],
"phone-number":[],
"mediafile":[],
"bonus-offer-summary":"Earn up to 50,000 bonus Points with the Qantas American Express Ultimate Card. Up to 7,500 bonus Points also available on the Qantas American Express Premium and Discovery Cards. Conditions and spend criteria apply.",
"bonus-offer-description":"You could earn up to 50,000 bonus points with the Qantas American Express Ultimate Card when you apply by 31 December 2013, are approved and meet the eligible spend criterias<sup>***</sup>. Also, you could earn up to 30,000 bonus points with the Qantas American Express Premium Card<sup>^^</sup> or up to 7,500 bonus points with the Qantas American Express Discovery Card<sup>**</sup> when you apply, are approved by 31 December 2013 and meet the eligible spend criteria.",
"show-bonus-offer":"",
"card-offerings":[{"card-name":"Qantas American Express Discovery Card",
                    "earning-points":"This credit card automatically earns Qantas Frequent Flyer points",
                    "website":"http://www.americanexpress.com/au/content/frequent-flyer-cards/qantas-discovery-card/?filter=qanseries&bkgd=3&PID=35&BUID=CCG&AFFID=Qantas&CRTV=Earn&PSKU=AQDB&sourcecode=25A996J001&CPID=100036881",
                    "contact-phone-number":"1300 736 978",
                    "usage-type":"Personal",
                    "card-level":"Classic",
                    "card-type-01":"American Express",
                    "annual-fee":"0","opt-in-fee":"0",
                    "supplementary-card-fee":"0",
                    "supplementary-card-fee-descriptor":"annual Card fee per Supplementary Card<sup>~</sup>",
                    "interest-rate":"20.74",
                    "interest-free-period":"Up to 44 days interest free on purchases when the closing balance (including any balance transfer or promotional amount) is paid in full by the statement due date<sup>$</sup>",
                    "earned-area":"<ul>\r\n\t<li>1 point per $1 eligible spend<sup>*</sup></li>\r\n\t<li>1 extra point per $1 spent in Australia on selected Qantas products &amp; services<sup>+</sup></li>\r\n\t<li>Uncapped points earning<sup>^</sup></li>\r\n\t<li>This introductory offer is available to new<sup>**</sup> American Express Cardmembers only.</li>\r\n</ul>\r\n",
                    "other-features":"<ul>\r\n\t<li>Interest rate of 20.74% p.a.<sup>#</sup></li>\r\n\t<li>Annual card fee of $0</li>\r\n\t<li>$0 annual Card fee per Supplementary Card<sup>~</sup></li>\r\n\t<li>Up to 44 days interest free on purchases when the closing balance (including any balance transfer or promotional amount) is paid in full by the statement due date<sup>$</sup></li>\r\n\t<li>5,000 points after $300 spend<sup>**</sup> on purchases in first 3 months of becoming a Cardmember</li>\r\n\t<li>2,500 points after first Card spend<sup>**</sup> in Australia on selected Qantas products &amp; services in Australia<sup>+</sup></li>\r\n\t<li>Introductory offer available to new<sup>**</sup> American Express Cardmembers only</li>\r\n</ul>\r\n"},
                    {"card-name":"Qantas American Express Premium Card",
                    "earning-points":"This credit card automatically earns Qantas Frequent Flyer points",
                    "website":"http://www.americanexpress.com/au/content/frequent-flyer-cards/qantas-premium-card/?filter=qanseries&bkgd=3&PID=35&BUID=CCG&AFFID=Qantas&CRTV=Earn&PSKU=MB9&sourcecode=25A9974001&CPID=100036882",
                    "contact-phone-number":"1800 040 398",
                    "usage-type":"Personal",
                    "card-level":"Gold",
                    "card-type-01":"American Express",
                    "annual-fee":"249","opt-in-fee":"0",
                    "supplementary-card-fee":"0",
                    "interest-rate":"20.74",
                    "cash-advance-rate":"0",
                    "interest-free-period":"Up to 44 days interest free on purchases when the closing balance (including any balance transfer or promotional amount) is paid in full by the statement due date<sup>$</sup>","earned-area":"<ul class=\"noindent\">\r\n\t<li>You can earn 2 points per dollar spent<sup>*</sup>. Click 'View Website' above for further details.</li>\r\n\t<li>Uncapped points earning<sup>^</sup></li>\r\n</ul>\r\n","other-features":"<ul class=\"noindent\">\r\n\t<li>Interest rate of 20.74% p.a.<sup>#</sup></li>\r\n\t<li>Annual card fee of $249</li>\r\n\t<li>$0 annual Card fee per Supplementary Card<sup>~</sup></li>\r\n\t<li>Up to 44 days interest free on purchases when the closing balance (including any balance transfer or promotional amount) is paid in full by the statement due date<sup>$</sup></li>\r\n\t<li>5,000 points after first Card spend<sup>^^</sup> on eligible purchases</li>\r\n\t<li>2,500 points after first Card spend<sup>^^</sup> on selected Qantas products &amp; services in Australia<sup>+</sup></li>\r\n\t<li>22,500 points after $500 spend within the first three months<sup>^^</sup></li>\r\n\t<li>This introductory offer available to new<sup>^^</sup> American Express Cardmembers only.</li>\r\n\t<li>Complimentary Domestic and Overseas Travel Insurance<sup>##</sup> when you pay for travel with your Card</li>\r\n\t<li>2 Qantas Club invitations per year<sup>~~</sup> after your first Card spend on selected Qantas products &amp; services<sup>+</sup> in Australia</li>\r\n</ul>\r\n"},{"card-name":"Qantas American Express Ultimate Card","earning-points":"This credit card automatically earns Qantas Frequent Flyer points","website":"http://www.americanexpress.com/au/content/frequent-flyer-cards/qantas-ultimate/?filter=qanseries",
                    "contact-phone-number":"1300 736 978",
                    "usage-type":"Personal",
                    "card-level":"Platinum",
                    "card-type-01":"American Express",
                    "interest-free-period":"Up to 44 days interest free on purchases when the closing balance (including any balance transfer or promotional amount) is paid in full by the statement due date<sup>$</sup>",
                    "earned-area":"<ul class=\"noindent\">\r\n\t<li>You can earn:</li>\r\n\t<li>3 Qantas points<sup>*</sup> per dollar spent on eligible Card purchases at:\r\n\t<ul type=\"disc\">\r\n\t\t<li>Tens of thousands of restaurants in Australia<sup>$$</sup></li>\r\n\t\t<li>Selected Qantas products and services in Australia<sup>+</sup></li>\r\n\t</ul>\r\n\t</li>\r\n\t<li>2 points per dollar spent* on eligible Card purchases at:\r\n\t<ul type=\"disc\">\r\n\t\t<li>airlines, accommodation, major cruise and tour operators paid directly or through travel agencies<sup>$$</sup></li>\r\n\t\t<li>Spend in foreign currency when overseas and online<sup>$$</sup></li>\r\n\t</ul>\r\n\t</li>\r\n\t<li>1 point per dollar spent* on eligible Card purchases at:\r\n\t<ul type=\"disc\">\r\n\t\t<li>All other providers, excluding those below</li>\r\n\t\t<li>Insurances offered by American Express</li>\r\n\t</ul>\r\n\t</li>\r\n\t<li>0.5 point per dollar spent* on eligible Card purchases at:\r\n\t<ul type=\"disc\">\r\n\t\t<li>Utilities which are gas, water and electricity providers</li>\r\n\t\t<li>Insurance offered by companies other than American Express</li>\r\n\t\t<li>Telecommunication providers which includes goods and services purchased from phone, mobile and internet service providers</li>\r\n\t\t<li>Government bodies including the Australian Taxation Office, Australia Post, federal/state and local government bodies</li>\r\n\t</ul>\r\n\t</li>\r\n</ul>\r\n","other-features":"<ul class=\"noindent\">\r\n\t<li>Interest rate of 20.74% p.a.<sup>#</sup></li>\r\n\t<li>Annual card fee of $450</li>\r\n\t<li>$0 annual Card fee per Supplementary Card<sup>~</sup></li>\r\n\t<li>Up to 44 days interest free on purchases when the closing balance (including any balance transfer or promotional amount) is paid in full by the statement due date<sup>$</sup></li>\r\n\t<li>5,000 points after first Card spend<sup>***</sup> on eligible purchases</li>\r\n\t<li>2,500 points after first Card spend<sup>***</sup> on selected Qantas products &amp; services in Australia<sup>+</sup></li>\r\n\t<li>42,500 points after $500 spend within the first three months<sup>***</sup></li>\r\n\t<li>Introductory offer available to new<sup>***</sup> American Express Cardmembers only</li>\r\n\t<li>1 Complimentary domestic return flight<sup>+++</sup> between selected Australian Capital cities after your first Card spend every year in Australia on selected Qantas products and services<sup>+</sup></li>\r\n\t<li>Complimentary Domestic and Overseas Travel Insurance<sup>##</sup> when you pay for travel with your Card</li>\r\n</ul>\r\n"},
                    {"card-name":"Test Offering - Sarah",
                    "annual-fee":"0",
                    "opt-in-fee":"0",
                    "supplementary-card-fee":"0",
                    "interest-rate":"0",
                    "cash-advance-rate":"0"}
                ]
}]
```

I want to handle this string in client side in jQuery as I am new to this I do not have idea anyone please suggest best idea to go for . This is basically a card info like this 'N' cards info will be getting in server reply I have to display a list of cards in a page if we click on one particular card will display all the details of the card and have to drag and drop and compare the cards.

So I am stuck in display as a list.
Can any one please help as soon as possible.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After parsing the JSON String with `JSON.parse(yourString)` or in case of jQuery `$.parseJSON(yourString)` you can use it as an object.

For example if you do this:

```
//yourString is the String provided in the question
var jsonObject = JSON.parse(yourString); 
alert(jsonObject.partner);
```

It will alert:

> American Express

Comment: Thank you Dropout I will test and post the results !

Comment: var obj = jQuery.parseJSON( '{ "name": "John", "age": "28"}' );
alert( obj.age === "28" )
; - this is showing true but if I put square brackets it is showing false as follows - var obj = jQuery.parseJSON( '[{ "name": "John", "age": "28"}]' );
alert( obj.age === "28" )
; Can you tell me why it does not work

Comment: Because you have a set/array.. This requires you to select the first element.. `obj[0].age`

Comment: Hi a quick doubt, 1. Can't we parse object key with hyphen (-) as used above "partner-code", it doesn't working it seems  and 2. if a string values is empty that should be like [] or ""

Comment: using hyphens shouldn't be a problem and as for the empty values it should remain in the state that's usedwhen it's not empty - if it's value is a string then "", if it's an array then []

Answer (score 2):

You can parse JSON string into JavaScript object using jQuery`s function [parseJSON](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/)
Documentation of the function and searching examples can guide you to your problem solving approach.

Comment: Thanks Oskars Pakers I am trying this now, will post if I get success!